# What is the proper way to structure this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis

I have the following sentence:

> The pact brought power; power, notoriety; and notoriety, the
>   authorities.

Is this the correct way to distribute the verb "brought" to the rest of the noun pairs that are strung out after it?

Sorry for the vague title, I don't know what this sentence structure is called.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the sentence is trying to say so it's difficult to know how best to say it.

Comment: Gapping is not a rule to be applied haphazardly. Try repetition: _The pact brought power. Power brought notoriety. And notoriety brought the authorities._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original is

> The pact brought power; power brought notoriety;/,/ ... and notoriety
>   brought the authorities.

(Some would quibble about the second semi-colon; I'd keep it for balance, in spite of the coordinator. I feel two commas doesn't lend the required gravitas, and two ellipses looks a little unprofessional. Fewer would probably contest the more obvious 'super-comma' usage in your deleted version:)

> The pact brought power; power, notoriety; and notoriety, the
>   authorities.

(though I think I'd use an ellipsis in place of the second semicolon to show a heightening of dramatic tension).

Omitting the repeats of the verb is known as **gapping**.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gapping) has:

> *gapping* [noun] Linguistics.
>
> a rule of transformational grammar by which repeated instances of a
>   verb are deleted from conjoined sentences, as in the deletion of
>   *brought* from
>
> *Mary brought the bread, John the cheese, and Bill the wine.*

Comment: Right on. If Ida seen this, I woudna made my comment above. Note, however, that Gapping only deletes repeated instances in right-branching languages. In Japanese and other OV languages, Gapping deletes all but the last identical verb in the sentence. So in those languages it'd be the equivalent of _Mary the bread, John the cheese, and Bill the wine bought_.